Why the Triac won't turn OFF?
I am trying to do a simple circuit includes a Triac:

it turns on fine, however the nightmare starts at the turning off point, when I turn it On and then turn it Off after 20 seconds maybe it just turns off normally and functions normally, but when I leave it a little bit On (1 minute approx) so the Triac gets hot, it just never turns off, unless I disconnect the 220 VAC mains. Don't know what is the problem.
Notes:

The Optocoupler have ZVC.

The heater draws approx to 7 A RMS so around 1500 W region

datasheet of the Triac : https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bta12.pdf

I didn't use a Heatsink because I was just seeing if the circuit was OK

I measured the Triac it works normally and have no internal short circuit (and tried to turn it On and then Off after the 20 seconds it just worked normally, unless I let it for a bit more time)

datasheet of the Optocoupler: https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/133874.pdf?srsltid=AfmBOor7G6qBWSTKMxjArMxUwz0ybh-XVYgrkN9oIHfETWZoZP9zt4cz


Please ask questions if needed, and sorry if I forgot to include any important information.

The part is rated to operate up to 125°C; have you measured the case temperature in operation?

yes I turned it off after it reached the 100 C but no higher than it

The voltage drop across a triac is about 2 V. At 7 amps, it's dissipating about 14 watts. That's enough to power a small soldering iron.
So if it gets hot without heat sink, it's not surprising.

The problem is not with the heat, it is totally not turning off (I measured it afterwards and it works normally and even tried it later)

To expand a little on what @DrMoishePippik mentioned, I also have a strong suspicion that what he mentioned could be the issue. What you're experiencing could be thermal runaway because there's no sufficient heat sink. As the TRIAC heats up, the holding current (the anode-cathode current required to keep the TRIAC conducting after it has been triggered) might be increasing. If the load current falls below this increased holding current, the TRIAC may turn off unexpectedly. Otherwise, if the TRIAC doesn't turn off as expected, it could be due to overheating, which affects its ability to return to its non-conducting state.
You could check the inrush current to make sure there's nothing suspicious going on at the load.

so you mean I need to check the gate current?

The holding current is usually the anode-cathode current needed for a TRIAC to keep conducting after a gate pulse, not the gate current.

@winny but my question even if the holding current increases, could it really reach 7 A of holding current?!

@HazardousVoltage My comment was directed towards Colin. You need a heatsink.

@winny Yes you're right. Thank you for the correction. I must have had my operations mixed up.
